# Why twitter tweet button does not work if appended dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I was just playing with Facebook and Twitter Like & Tweet Button respectively. When I noticed that dynamically appended Twitter button does not work but manually added Anchor works. Why is it so?

Here's The Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5VrX/)

You can see it is not working.

Code:

```
$("body").append('<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-dnt="true" data-count="none" data-via="SitesTwitter">Tweet</a>');
```

Comment: Can you update your fiddle for the button code instead of just anchor tags? In your fiddle, both of the shown items take me to twitter.com. I am not sure what else is supposed to happen

Comment: well, IDK man i have just used it first time. In fiddle, one button which is manually added works and also not redirects. But the second one does redirect.

Comment: woah man then i think it will be just the JSFiddle issue. I give a check on my localhost if it works i am right back here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How interesting. The current code it's actually works for me on: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/punfx but I got the same issue of you on your Fiddle.

I think it's a timing issue. You have to inject the `twitter-wjs` once you added dynamically your button. I believe this script will probably scan the page to modifying any link that has the `twitter-share-button` class, or something like that. So if you add the button after the execution of that script, your link won't be scanned.

Comment: In fact, if you take a look at https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet, you can see that the script tag is after the link tag, and not viceversa, as in your example.

Comment: thanks :D and now what to do man ? @Nielslnc also have answered. Now who's answer should i accept ?

Comment: He was first, so give it to him :)

Answer (score 5):

This is because the Javascript that converts the link into a twitter link is fired before (onload probably) you add the new link with javascript: if you delete the  section in your html and call it in the js after you add the button, it works (or leave it and call it after you add the button)

```
 $("body").append('<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-dnt="true" data-count="none" data-via="SitesTwitter">Tweet</a>');
 ! function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
```

Check the  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5VrX/)